# Selenium to load full website

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, selenium

There is a website that list first 20 items and them if i scroll down it loads the next 20 items. Say if the website is to list 100 items then I have to scroll down to the last item 5 times to get all the 100 listed.

I use selenium in java to get the webpage, But It gets only the first 20 items.I want it to load all the items in the page and get me the html of the page.

And after showing some 100 items, the page generates a div that acts as show more like below.

```
 <div id="show-more-results" class="dont-show">
 Show more results
 </div>
```

Now I want to click `show more results`. I have a working code until this part. 
But the clicking `show-more-results` part is not working.

```
public class seleniumTest
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    String link = "http://www.some.com";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(link);
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) {
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 5000)", "");
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("show-more-results")).click();
}
}
```

The last line of the code is not working now. ie `driver.findElement(By.id("show-more-results")).click();`

url used :

```
http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/micromax~brand/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dprice_asc&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=d92e01d2-38f2-46bb-82be-752e93e9ce88
```

Any Help?

Comment: The page probably makes another request to the server when you scroll down, so you may have to find out that request URL and POST body (if any) and recreate it. Does that make sense?

Comment: What you mean under 'is not working now'? No click performed? Exception? THen you execute script visually this 'Show More Results' button appears?

Comment: Can you share the actual url used?

Comment: http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/micromax~brand/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dprice_asc&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=d92e01d2-38f2-46bb-82be-752e93e9ce88

Comment: find the url above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `window.scrollBy()` javascript function:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 3000)", "");
```

And, you want to probably do this multiple times in a loop:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1) {
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 3000)", "");
    Thread.sleep(1000L);  // needed to wait for the page load
}
```

Comment: Modified the question now... See if you can help.

Comment: @user2186465 are you sure, there is the button at the moment of searching it?

Comment: yes i'm sure...i can share the screen shot if you want...it comes after loading four pages from top....run the program with chrome driver and see it can list all the 198 items just with the help of scrollBy...could you see the button or not???

Comment: @user2186465 does adding `Thread.sleep(3000L);` after the loop and before finding the button help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
//or
//scroll down
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
//scroll up
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

Comment: please help for the modified question.